# Write bool and aggregate query in C#

Tags: elasticsearch, lambda, nest, elasticsearch-plugin

Guys i want to write nest query which will fetch distinct result with filter.
I want to write below part of `Elasticsearch` code in c# using `Nest`.

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
"query": {
    "bool": {            
        "must": [
           {
              "terms": {
                "ID": [ "5","6" ]          
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "ProjectID": [ "54"]
              }
            }
        ]
      }
   },
  "aggs": {
  "my_fields": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "ID",
    "size": 0
     }
   }
  }
 }
```

I'am new to Elasticsearch.Help me to write it in lambda expression. I wrote some code but don't know how to add square brackets in query

```
var ElasticSearchNetQuery = new { aggs = new { distinctRespId = new { cardinality = new { field = "RespID" }, query = new { @bool = new { must= new { } } } }, size = 10000 } };
```

Comment: JSON `[ "5", "6"]` can be translated in C# as : `new[] { "5", "6" }`. Is it what you're looking for ?

Comment: Ohh friend I made some changes and it worked but it not allowing me to put different words inside new[] term like ID and ProjectID, getting compile time error

var ElasticSearchNetQuery = new { aggs = new { distinctRespId = new { cardinality = new { field = "RespID" }, query = new { @bool = new { must = new[] { new { terms = new { QID = "" } }, new { terms = new { ProjectID = "" } } } } } } }, size = 10000 };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = client.Search<object>(sd => sd
    .Index("<index name>")
    .Type("<type name>")
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(
                m => m.Terms("ID", new[] { "5", "6" }),
                m => m.Terms("ProjectID", new[] { "54" }))))
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("my_fields", t => t
            .Field("ID")
            .Size(0)));
```

Comment: you've written lambda query beautifully, but there is something wrong m getting all the records, filters not working :(

Comment: I don't see a reason why it should not work. It's pretty simple. Can you explain what extra results are you receiving?

Comment: This query returning all the records from 'type', it means filters not working.

Comment: Are you getting any result in which the value of field "ID" is neither 5 nor 6 or value of field "ProjectID" is not 54? If so, please share your mapping and some sample result documents which you think should not have matched but did match.

Comment: Hey your query is absolutely right but Rest API plugin and C# returning different result.....sad thanx bdw :|